# How to get all SPL token mints of a wallet address?

Tags: spl-token, token, mint

Using `getTokenAccountsByOwner` we can get all token accounts and using `getTokenAccountBalanace` we can use the token account to get it's balance. However I was wondering what would be the most efficient and fastest method to get all *mints* of tokens held by an account? What I want to do is to display all tokens held by a user but unsure how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [findDataByOwner](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#findAllByOwner) via Metaplex js library.

Example:

```
const myNfts = await metaplex
    .nfts()
    .findAllByOwner({ owner: metaplex.identity().publicKey })
    .run();
```